# Matrix Visuals - How to remove the grand total and keep subtotals?

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI Desktop, is there a way to keep the subtotals and remove the grand total in a matrix?

For example, in the following matrix, it doesn't make sense to add values for multiple years of sales (thus, also to keep a grand total row), but it is necessary to add values for different months in the same year:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can hide the grand total in **Format > Subtotals**:
First enable **Per row level**. Then disable the switch that just appeared below with the desired column title (*ano* in this case).

Answer (score 4):

It's still not yet possible in Power BI to turn off `Grand total` while keeping `Subtotals`. (It's weird that they have separate control panels for `Subtotals` and `Grand total` but the toggle option is combined as one under `Subtotals`.)

I've come up with a cosmetic workaround which may achieve the same result:

[image: cosmetic]

For `Grand total`, you can set the font color and background color to white (or the same as your visual background) so that the total is invisible in the visual.

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: It is already possible in the latest version of PBI Desktop. Just downloaded it and it works!

Comment: would you please show us how, i have the latest version of Power BI application
Thanks